# Some issues with fading large div

Tags: javascript

I have been using this site for awhile but never posted, I ususally found my anser.

However I seem to have a valid question regarding fading.
I have a simple javascript fade in script, with a functional cross browser opacity setting function.  I am trying to fade in a large part of the webpage, but the large size or complexity of the elements in the div seems to really slow down the render in a couple browsers.  In some browsers it works too fast, so I know the code works.

Does anyone know anything about the limitations of opacity rendering in different browsers?

I know I could overlay a simpler div with opacity but this just adds code when the existing code works, just not sure why there should be such drastic differences in the time it takes to apply opacity between the browsers.

Comment: can you post the method you employ for fading, and to how many elements it applies at the same time..

Comment: Also the browsers it has issues in would be helpful as well.

Comment: Problems, @Aliester, the browsers it has problems in. ;)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has fadein/fadeout. Have you tried them?